# Selecting subsets of a grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, subset

The data I used can be found [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d) (the "sq.txt" file).

Below is a summary of the data:

```
> summary(sq)
    behaviour           date         squirrel          time     
resting     :983   2017-06-28: 197   22995  : 127   09:30:00:  17  
travelling  :649   2017-06-26: 160   22758  : 116   08:00:00:  16  
feeding     :344   2017-06-30: 139   23080  : 108   16:25:00:  15  
OOS         :330   2017-07-18: 110   23089  : 100   08:11:00:  13  
vocalization:246   2017-06-27:  99   23079  :  97   08:31:00:  13  
social      : 53   2017-06-29:  96   22865  :  95   15:24:00:  13  
(Other)     : 67   (Other)   :1871   (Other):2029   (Other) :2585
```

Each `squirrel` has a number of observations that correspond to a number of different behaviours (`behaviour`).

For example, `squirrel` 22995 was observed 127 times. These 127 observations correspond to different `behaviour` categories: 7 `feeding`, 1 `territorial`, 55 `resting`, etc. I then need to divide the number of each `behaviour` by the total number of observations (i.e. `feeding` = 7/127, `territorial` = 1/127, `resting` = 55/127, etc.) to get proportions of time spent doing each `behaviour`.

I already have grouped my observations by `squirrel` using the `dplyr` package.

**Is there a way, using** `dplyr`, **for me to calculate proportions for one column**  (`behaviour`) **based on the total observations for a column** (`squirrel`) **where the values have been grouped?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
sq %>% 
  count(squirrel, behaviour) %>% 
  group_by(squirrel) %>% 
  mutate(p = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  # add this line to see result for squirrel 22995
  filter(squirrel == 22995)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   squirrel [1]
  squirrel behaviour         n       p
     <int> <chr>         <int>   <dbl>
1    22995 feeding           7 0.0551 
2    22995 nest_building     4 0.0315 
3    22995 OOS               9 0.0709 
4    22995 resting          55 0.433  
5    22995 social            6 0.0472 
6    22995 territorial       1 0.00787
7    22995 travelling       32 0.252  
8    22995 vocalization     13 0.102
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to include zero counts for squirrels where a behaviour was not observed, one way is to use `tidyr::complete()`. That generates NA by default, which you may want to replace with zero.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sq %>% 
  count(squirrel, behaviour) %>% 
  complete(squirrel, behaviour) %>% 
  group_by(squirrel) %>% 
  mutate(p = n/sum(n, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(n = 0, p = 0)) %>%
  filter(squirrel == 22995)

# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   squirrel [1]
   squirrel behaviour         n       p
      <int> <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    22995 dead           0    0      
 2    22995 feeding        7.00 0.0551 
 3    22995 grooming       0    0      
 4    22995 nest_building  4.00 0.0315 
 5    22995 OOS            9.00 0.0709 
 6    22995 resting       55.0  0.433  
 7    22995 social         6.00 0.0472 
 8    22995 territorial    1.00 0.00787
 9    22995 travelling    32.0  0.252  
10    22995 vigilant       0    0      
11    22995 vocalization  13.0  0.102
```

Comment: Wow! Yes. But, is there a way to make the behaviours where there were 0 observations also show up in the proportions? For my purposes, 0 is also meaningful.

Comment: Also, silly follow up question: why do all the other columns (`date` and `time`) get deleted after?

Comment: Answer to second question: just run `count` by itself and see what happens :) basically it's the same as `group_by` followed by `summarise`.

Comment: Edited to answer first question.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I have been trying to do.